# Facing Issue with c# and crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have created a viewmodel as salesoffer. which is linked to a view which joins almost 4 tables and returns the records. When the view is executed is displays 8 records which have same unit id but other columns are unique. Now when i call those fields in crystal report, report is only showing first record but '8' times. I ran the profiler it is fine from db as view data is same what is being expected but on the report side in details section i am having this problem.

Comment: Usually, that is no happened. Please show your report structure and sql query with result

Comment: It was related to the sql view created. It had too many joins which was the issue. Once i simplified the view it worked fine thank you